# Dependency issue trying to deploy R Shiny app to shinyapps.io through Databricks

Tags: r, shiny, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to deploy an R Shiny app to shinyapps.io directly from Databricks, but I keep running into an issue during the deployment process. The deployment fails with an error related to fetching package sources. Here is an example of the error message I receive after I run `rsconnect:deployApp()`:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1386608045 child_task_status=failed: Error building image: Error fetching Rcpp (1.0.11) source. <RepositoryPackageSource repo='https://cloud.r-project.org'> unable to satisfy package: Rcpp (1.0.11)
```

This is my app (it's the Shiny demo app):

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've investigated it enough to know that if I go try deploying, installing whatever package is not installed, and trying again, I can finally get it to deploy. For an app with just a "shiny" dependency, I have to install the following packages manually:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
install.packages('cli')
install.packages('commonmark')
install.packages('digest')
install.packages('fs')
install.packages('glue')
install.packages('jsonlite')
install.packages('rlang')
install.packages('withr')
install.packages('later')
install.packages('lifecycle')
install.packages('htmltools')
install.packages('promises')
install.packages('fontawesome')
install.packages('sass')
install.packages('httpuv')
install.packages('bslib')
install.packages('httr')
```

If I expand the dependencies, for example, if I included `library(plotly)`,
the list of packages I have to install manually grows. I cannot replicate this locally. It only happens on the Databricks environment.

I also attempted to install shiny through a shell script to see if it installs what is needed, but that doesn't solve the issue.